Voltage Drop Of DC transmisson line

"A transportation vehicle operating on DC and drawing 300 A is powered by two separate sources located 8 km apart, with voltages of 500 V and 520 V. Considering the resistance of the round-trip conductors is 0.05 ohm/km, determine the value and location of the lowest voltage drop along the line."
How am I supposed to go about solving this question? I know that the voltage drop of a DC line is (deltaU = 2 * I * Rh * L ) but how am I supposed to find the lowest point?

Write the equation for the voltage drop vs. position.  Differentiate. Set to zero, solve for minimum.

(Sanity check: 20 V/(8 km * .05 Ω/km) = 50 A - better not draw less than that.)

This can be solved by nodal analysis:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Define resistances in terms of distance \$L\$:
$$ R_1 = R_3 = 0.05L $$
$$ R_2 = R_4 = 0.05(8-L) $$
The presence of R3 and R4, and the factor of 0.05, depend on how you interpret "round trip resistance", which is not immediately clear to me from the question as it stands. If the same conductive material is used around the entire loop (which would not be the case for a tram system where current returns via rails), then this model is fine.
Apply KCL:
$$ I_3 = I_1 + I_2 $$
Apply KVL:
$$ V_A - V_1 - V_T - V_3 = 0 $$
$$ V_B - V_2 - V_T - V_4 = 0 $$
Ohm's law:
$$ V_1 = I_1R_1 $$
$$ V_2 = I_2R_2 $$
$$ V_3 = I_1R_3 $$
$$ V_4 = I_2R_4 $$
You'd usually combine some of those into single steps, but I've kept the three laws Ohm's, KCL, KVL distinct just for clarity.
The first goal is to obtain an expression for tram voltage \$V_T\$ in terms of \$L\$, which will require some manipulation of those simultaneous equations, using whatever techniques you are comfortable with. Once you have that equation, differentiate with respect to \$L\$, and find the turning points, where gradient is zero:
$$ \frac{dV_T}{dL} = 0 $$
